# AppleScript : Repeat until document.getElementsByClassName is true

Tags: applescript, safari, javascript

I'm trying to wait for a element to be available on Safari before the script can continue

```
repeat
    set JSChecker to "Not Found Yet"
    try
        tell application "Safari Technology Preview"

            set JSChecker to do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('field type-person field-ID')[0].innerHTML;" in tab 3 of window 1
        end tell
    on error
        set JSChecker to "Not Found Yet"
    end try

    if JSChecker is equal to "Not Found Yet" then
        display notification "no found"
    else
        delay 0.2
    end if
end repeat
```

although I keep having an error even using TRY, when the element is not here 
How can I right the code in order to wait that "JSChecker" is not a missing value

Comment: What is the error ?